# Как убрать точу из чисел с плавающей точкой?

Tags: php, api, double

подскажите пожалуйста **как убрать точку из чисел с плавающей точкой** допустим если есть **12.50** сделать **1250**. Не спрашивайте почему просто есть один сервис интеграция которого нуждается в этом. Буду рад если кто-ни-будь поможет

Язык программирования **PHP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно убрать плавающую точку: `str_replace('.', '', $float);`, где $float - значение, которое нужно изменить.
Если как ты написал нужно, чтобы из числа 10 - сделать 10.00 то`sprintf("%.2f", $int);` где $int - значение integer

Answer (score 2):

Если знаков после запятой всегда 2, то можно просто умножить на 100

```
$float = 12.50;   
$result = (int)$float*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tt = str_replace(".", "", "12.50");
echo $tt;//1250
```

Comment: а как сделать если переменная 15.3 а нужно сделать 1530 &

Comment: Всё как в примере от @kachulin, только вместо int приводите к float

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = (int) bcmul(strval($float), '100');
```

На всякий:
Перечень функции BC Math (поддерживают числа любого размера и точности):

bcadd — Сложить 2 числа произвольной точности

bccomp — Сравнение двух чисел произвольной точности

bcdiv — Операция деления для чисел произвольной точности

bcmod — Получает остаток от деления чисел с произвольной точностью

bcmul — Умножение двух чисел с произвольной точностью

bcpow — Возведение в степень чисел с произвольной точностью

bcpowmod — Возводит одно число в степень другого и возвращает остаток от деления результата на третье число

bcscale — Задает количество чисел после десятичной точки по умолчанию для всех bc math функций.

bcsqrt — Извлекает квадратный корень из числа с заданной точностью

bcsub — Вычитает одно число из другого с заданной точностью